# Implement a TaskQueue (like Celery) with ETA/Countdown

Tags: celery, message-queue, messaging, task-queue, google-cloud-pubsub

Many popular task queues (such as Google GAE TaskQueue, Celery) have the ETA/Countdown feature, which allows a task to be put into the queue after xxx seconds.

I am working on a project that needs a task queue with the ETA feature. However, there are some limitations that I have to use the Google Pubsub messaging system. Pubsub does not have the ETA feature. I am wondering how to implement a reliable and scalable ETA mechanism for a task queue. Both general architecture ideas and actual code samples are welcome.

Our system enqueues 600-2000 tasks/second, and about 10% of them need to have ETA. It is a distributed system and performance-critical.

I tried to trace the source [code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/7d574b60db9eb67e2e81eb16929313e941e772db/celery/app/task.py) of celery, but couldn't find the actual logic of handling the ETA. It would also be good if someone can point me to the file/code of Celery that handle ETA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have found how Celery did it. In [eventlet.py](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/88c99585fc64ae61b6c2c99dd113a2448fcefa05/celery/concurrency/eventlet.py), it uses eventlet's spawn_after feature to delay the worker creation "ETA" seconds.

`secs = max(eta - monotonic(), 0)
 g = self._spawn_after(secs, entry)`

Comment: does Celery support using PubSub as message broker? If so, can you point me to the PubSub Python library to use?